# Enviar JSON php

Tags: php, android, json, mysqli, webservice

Estoy teniendo problemas al enviar un JSON desde un webService PHP y MySQL, dejo el código de la consulta y del fetch assoc, la consulta ya la he comprobado y es correcta, en phpMyAdmin me la hace perfecta, el problema es que cuando recibo el JSON en Android recibo cosas que no deberían formar parte del JSON:

```
$consulta= "SELECT `id`,`actividad`,`lugar`,`fecha` FROM `planes`  WHERE `usuario`= '".$usuario."' ORDER BY `id` DESC";

$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $consulta);   
$rawdata = array();
$i=0;

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $rawdata[$i] = $row;
    $i++;
 }

echo json_encode($rawdata);
```

y esto es lo que recibo en android según el log:

> {"0":"1","id":"1","1":"Prueba","actividad":"Prueba","2":"Madrid","lugar":"Madrid","3":"01/12/2019","fecha":"01/12/2019"}

esta metiendo cosas que no son, debería ser

> {"id":"1", "actividad":"Prueba","lugar":"Madrid","fecha":"01/12/2019"}

No sé sin son las barras (/), si es la codificación utf8, ...

¿Alguna idea?

Muchas gracias, un saludo

Comment: Te esta mostrando la posicion del array que ocupa cada dato y dsp el nombre asociativo mas cada dato, ej: El primer dato en el array es el id que es 1 por lo que en un array ocupa la posicion 0 entonces, en la posicion 0 tenes el valor 1  que a su vez lo podes llamar como el nombre asociativo "id" que tambien va a devolver 1

Comment: @Juan y cómo lo puedo hacer para obtener el resultado que yo quiero? Que tengo que modificar en el While?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La función está correcta, ya que `mysqli_fetch_array($result)` es equivalente a usar `mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_BOTH)` que retorna los nombres de las columnas con sus respectivos valores y las posiciones de las columnas con sus valores.

Si quieres que `mysqli_fetch_array()` retorne solo los nombres con los valores te recomiendo añadir `MYSQLI_ASSOC` como segundo parámetro:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    $rawdata[] = $row;
}
```

Fíjate que tampoco usamos `$i` ya que al hacer `$rawdata[] = valor` estamos ingresando datos automáticamente al array.

Comment: me funcionó solo con el MYSQLI_ASSOC, muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

puedes usar directamente array_push ($rawdata, $row);